# Group by and aggregate on a column with array in PySpark

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aggregate-functions

I have the below PySpark dataframe. column_2 is of complex data type array<map<string,bigint>>

```
Column_1 Column_2                 Column_3
A        [{Mat=7},{Phy=8}]        ABC
A        [{Mat=7},{Phy=8}]        CDE
B        [{Mat=6},{Phy=7}]        ZZZ
```

I have to group by on column 1 and column 2 and get the minimum aggregate of column 3.

The problem is when I try to group by column 1 and column 2 it's giving me an error

> cannot be used as grouping expression because the data type is not an orderable data type

Is there a way to include this column in group by or to aggregate it in some way. The values in column_2 will always be same for a key value in column_1

Expected output:

```
Column_1 Column_2                Column_3
A        [{Mat=7},{Phy=8}]       ABC
B        [{Mat=6},{Phy=7}]       ZZZ
```

Is it possible to do a collect list of all value in aggregate function and flatten it and remove duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The values in column_2 will always be same for a key value in column_1

If so, then you can just take the [`first`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.first.html#pyspark.sql.functions.first) value in the group.

Test dataframe:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('A', 'ABC', 7, 8),
     ('A', 'CDE', 7, 8),
     ('B', 'ZZZ', 6, 7)],
    ['Column_1', 'Column_3', 'm', 'p'])
df = df.select(
    'Column_1',
    F.array(F.create_map(F.lit('Mat'), 'm'), F.create_map(F.lit('Phy'), 'p')).alias('Column_2'),
    'Column_3'
)
df.show(truncate=False)
print(df.dtypes)
# +--------+------------------------+--------+
# |Column_1|Column_2                |Column_3|
# +--------+------------------------+--------+
# |A       |[{Mat -> 7}, {Phy -> 8}]|ABC     |
# |A       |[{Mat -> 7}, {Phy -> 8}]|CDE     |
# |B       |[{Mat -> 6}, {Phy -> 7}]|ZZZ     |
# +--------+------------------------+--------+

# [('Column_1', 'string'), ('Column_2', 'array<map<string,bigint>>'), ('Column_3', 'string')]
```

Aggregation:

```py
df2 = df.groupBy('Column_1').agg(
    F.first('Column_2').alias('Column_2'),
    F.min('Column_3').alias('Column_3')
)
df2.show(truncate=False)
# +--------+------------------------+--------+
# |Column_1|Column_2                |Column_3|
# +--------+------------------------+--------+
# |A       |[{Mat -> 7}, {Phy -> 8}]|ABC     |
# |B       |[{Mat -> 6}, {Phy -> 7}]|ZZZ     |
# +--------+------------------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I possibly misunderstood your question. If I did, no harm someone can benefit.

I thought you wanted to select the minimum aggregated sum of values in `Column_2`. I therefore modified the dataframe slightly to ensure group `A` has multiple values. see df

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('A', 'ABC', 7, 8),
     ('A', 'CDE', 3, 8),
     ('B', 'ZZZ', 6, 7)],
    ['Column_1', 'Column_3', 'm', 'p'])
df = df.select(
    'Column_1',
    F.array(F.create_map(F.lit('Mat'), 'm'), F.create_map(F.lit('Phy'), 'p')).alias('Column_2'),
    'Column_3'
)
df.show(truncate=False)
```

df

```
+--------+------------------------+--------+
|Column_1|Column_2                |Column_3|
+--------+------------------------+--------+
|A       |[{Mat -> 7}, {Phy -> 8}]|ABC     |
|A       |[{Mat -> 3}, {Phy -> 8}]|CDE     |
|B       |[{Mat -> 6}, {Phy -> 7}]|ZZZ     |
+--------+------------------------+--------+
```

Solution

If my assumption is right

1. Extract values of the key value pair in `Column_2` into a column called `filter`
2. Aggregate them by summing them. Save out come in `filter`
3. Order by `Column_1` and `filter`
4. drop duplicates with subset `Column_1`

Code below

```
new = df.withColumn("filter",F.expr("aggregate(transform(Column_2,x -> map_values(x)[0] ),cast(0 as bigint),(x,i)->x+i)")).orderBy('Column_1',desc('filter')).dropDuplicates(['Column_1']).drop('filter')
new.show()
    
+--------+------------------------+--------+
|Column_1|Column_2                |Column_3|
+--------+------------------------+--------+
|A       |[{Mat -> 7}, {Phy -> 8}]|ABC     |
|B       |[{Mat -> 6}, {Phy -> 7}]|ZZZ     |
+--------+------------------------+--------+
```